# No gaps between divs

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

See jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/joe_young/ubgpseyt/

My problem is I don't want the gap between the `whatFontHead` and `whatFont` when it has slid in.

I am trying to change the font of a text area from a menu, using this menu (with CSS & jQuery):

```
<h1>Choose a font</h1>

<div id="whatFontHead">Change Font</div>
<div id="whatFont">
    <p id="to-os">Open Sans</p>
    <p id="to-vd">Verdana</p>
    <p id="to-sl">Slabo</p>
    <p id="to-cg">Courgette</p>
</div>
```

The head bit which is displayed, and onclick the `whatFont` `slideToggle`s

```
<div id="whatFont">
    <p id="to-os">Open Sans</p>
    <p id="to-vd">Verdana</p>
    <p id="to-sl">Slabo</p>
    <p id="to-cg">Courgette</p>
</div>
```

So `onclick` of `whatFontHead,` `whatFont` slides in, and this works.
However, there is a gap between the two: http://jsfiddle.net/joe_young/ubgpseyt/

I have set their respective top and bottom margins to `0`, and to `-1px`, and also changing **all** the margins to `0`, but this doesn't fix it either.

I've also looked at this question: '[Gap between empty divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223781/gap-between-empty-divs),' however my `divs` actually have content in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gaps is caused by margin collapsing and actually is caused by margin in `#whatFont` child element. More information on this topic you will find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19719427/2416924

Adding this should fix the problem:

```
#whatFont :first-child {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

On your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ubgpseyt/3/

Answer (score 1):

Just add this css:

```
#whatFont p:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ubgpseyt/5/

The issue is caused by `<p>` having a margin from the user agent default. On Chrome, `<p> has:`-webkit-margin-before: 1em;` by default

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubgpseyt/10/)**

Just add `margin-top: 0` to `#to-os`

```
#to-os {
 margin-top: 0;
}
```

To overcome such issues i recommend to use **[normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)**